# Mysql Db Changes not reflected in command line but able to see it in my application

Tags: mysql

i am using mysql as my db server 
and i recently using mysql 5.0 version 
on my newly configure laptop and  i am not able to see they my db change done by through programming in sql command line or any sql editor but i am see those changes in my application ui 
like if i add any records through my application so it get inserted in databse and i am able see it on my application but not in my database 
i am curious how that would be possible 
please share your knowledge if you know anything

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Maybe your queries has not been commited to your database, and are in a cached state? Do you use an ORM?

Comment: yes i am using ORM but before it work fine on my desktop and i moved to my laptop now ,i am sure for that